# ng-repeat item in title attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with displaying a tooltip when using `title` attribute in an element inside `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
  <collapsable-panel is-open="true" class="custom-class" title="{{item.name}}">
         @*  other code *@
  </collapsable-panel>
</div>
```

With this I'm getting an error

```
Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{item.name}}] starting at [{item.name}}].
```

Would appreciate any ideas why this happens.

Comment: try without curly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ng-attr to bind the title.

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items">
  <collapsable-panel is-open="true" class="custom-class" ng-attr-title="{{item.name}}">
         @*  other code *@
  </collapsable-panel>
</div>
```